# Android Kotlin: How to reset an alarm within a broadcast receiver/alarm

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

Use-case: I want my app to announce the current time ("the current time is $hour $minute") at 5 minute intervals.  The idea is to help me stay on time while getting ready in the morning, so it needs to fire at the exact time, every 5 minutes, without fail, even with the screen turned off.

Problem: Since Android alarmManager's SetRepeating is no longer exact, I am using SetExactandAllowWhileIdle.  I can't figure out how to set a new alarm within my broadcast receiver to make it repeating. Is it possible to set an alarm within a running alarm class in Kotlin?  The only examples I can find are in Java.

I've also read that Android limits alarms, so even with SetExactandAllowWhileIdle you are limited to one alarm every 1-15 minutes, so it's possible this may still not work.  Is there a better way to do all this that I am missing?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    var isRunning: Boolean = false
    var tts: TextToSpeech? = null
    private lateinit var alarmMgr: AlarmManager
    private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var alarmMgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        var intent = Intent(this, MyAlarm::class.java)
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            if (!isRunning) {
                button.text = getString(R.string.stop)
                button.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorRed))
                isRunning = true
                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                calendar.set(
                    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    calendar.get(HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    calendar.get(MINUTE),
                    0
                )
                startAnnouncing(calendar)
            } //end if !isRunning
            else if (isRunning) {
                button.text = getString(R.string.start)
                button.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorGreen))
                isRunning = false
                alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Announcing stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } //end if isRunning
        } //end button OnClickListener

        tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)

    } //end onCreate

    private fun startAnnouncing(calendar: Calendar) {

        var alarmMgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        var intent = Intent(this, MyAlarm::class.java)
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)

        alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis + 1000*60*1,
            pendingIntent
        )
        Toast.makeText(this, "Announcing started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } //end startAnnouncing

    class MyAlarm : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(
            context: Context,
            intent: Intent
        ) {
            val ttsService = Intent(context, TTS::class.java)
            context.startService(ttsService)

            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.set(
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                calendar.get(HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(MINUTE),
                0
            )
    //THIS is where I'd like to call a new alarm to make this a repeating alarm cycle

        } //end onReceive

    } //end MyAlarm

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // set US English as language for tts
            val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.US)
        }

    } //end onInit

    public override fun onDestroy() {
        // Shutdown TTS
        if (tts != null) {
            tts!!.stop()
            tts!!.shutdown()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
        //alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent)
    } //end onDestroy

} //end MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've also read that Android limits alarms, so even with SetExactandAllowWhileIdle you are limited to one alarm every 1-15 minutes

This is correct, according the the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) "Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes"

You may be able to get away with using `setExactandAllowWhileIdle`, but I don't recall if there is documentation on how long it takes before the device goes into low power/doze mode. Also, it might be even more likely to work how you want if you add the app to the battery optimization exception list. See [these docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) for Google's suggestions on dealing with doze/app standby.

Another option appears to be `setAlarmClock` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent))) but I recommend against this as the intended use of this is for creating an alarm clock style application

Comment: Yeah it's very frustrating that this app would've been easy to write years ago with SetRepeating, and is not even possible anymore.

I had not seen the battery optimization exception list option, thank you for pointing that out.